# MySql Database not updating correctly when getting request via app

Tags: mysql, ios, database

I'm having a rather weird problem (I think). 
The user can add a contact to a tableView and this contact also gets saved to a mysql database. (the app is interacting with a php file on my server)
The weird thing is that he seems to pick one of the added values at random and adds them to the database (sometimes the firstname, sometimes the number). The php code is definitely not the problem, I got it checked here. (Also when not doing it from the app he adds everything accordingly) 
So I guess it has something to do with my code:

```
         NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bladesserver/phpFile.php?name=%@",firstName];

        NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bladesserver/phpFile.php?lastname=%@",lastName];

        NSString *strURL3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://blades/phpFile.php?number=%@",number];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL2]];
        NSString *strResult2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *dataURL3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL3]];
        NSString *strResult3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        ;
        NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
            NSLog(@"%@", strResult2);
           NSLog(@"%@", strResult3);
```

Btw: In the tableView the contacts get display correctly (firstname, lastname, number).

Comment: why is this tagge with `php` ?

Comment: Because I add my values to a mysql database via php? I deleted the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, kinda obvious if you think about it:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bladesserver/phpFile.php?name=%@&lastname=%@&number=%@",firstName, lastname, number];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

Comment: Just some advice in case anyone else things that this is a solution - `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous call and will block your app until it returns. If you are doing this with a non-local URL, the data could takes some time to download, and your app will be not be able to respond during, and look like it has hung.

Comment: What would you advice to do instead?

Comment: NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection is one way to use make asynchronous URL requests. Have a look at the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)